# JLayeredPane: How to check if component has another drawn under it

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have a JLayeredPane. On that I place several components. Those components are classes that extend jPanel. All components are placed in the same depth layer. Each component may or may not have other component/components totally/partially above/below it. When I click on the components the topmost is clicked.

How do I check if there are more components below the topomost at the point where I clicked? How can I "pass" the click event to one of those or to many of those components below?

EDIT: A working example

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class JavaJLayeredPane {
    JFrame frame;
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel Panel1;
    JPanel panel;

 public void createUI()
 {
    frame = new JFrame("Items one ove the other");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    frame.add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);

    ArrayList<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
    colorList.add(Color.red);
    colorList.add(Color.yellow);
    colorList.add(Color.blue);
    colorList.add(Color.green);
    colorList.add(Color.cyan);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    String mytext="no"+ i;
    Panel1 = new myarea(mytext);
    Panel1.setBackground(colorList.get(i));
    if (i==0){Panel1.setBounds(210, 110, 20, 20);}
    if (i==1){Panel1.setBounds(200, 100, 150, 150);}
    if (i==2){Panel1.setBounds(250, 110, 170, 120);}
    if (i==3){Panel1.setBounds(180, 130, 110, 110);}
    if (i==4){Panel1.setBounds(450, 150, 50, 50);}
    layeredPane.add(Panel1, new Integer(0), 0);
    }

    panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaJLayeredPane overlapPane = new JavaJLayeredPane();
            overlapPane.createUI();
}

   public class myarea extends JPanel implements  MouseListener{
        public String areaname;

    public myarea(String myname) {
        addMouseListener(this);
        areaname=myname;
    }

//LISTENERS    
    @Override
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){
}
    @Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt){
}
    @Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
    if(evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,areaname ) ;    
    }

  }
    @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt){
  }
    @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){
  }
 }


 }
```

If we click on a rectangle that is abode another we get it's name. How do we check if there is another rectangle below, and if yes, how do we get it's properties?

Comment: Sounds like really poor use of JLayeredPane IMO. Maybe a runnable example may change my mind.

Comment: @ peeskillet. My case is too complicated to post here. By why poor use? There is nothing wrong when placing components one over the other in a JLayeredPane and there is nothing wrong when one needs to be able to access all the overlaped components by mouse. Is there?

Comment: Why even use a JlayeredPane if you're going to place all the components on the same layer? That's the point I was getting at.

Comment: I agree that it sounds a bit suspect, having all components on the same layer, but you could add the MouseListener to the JLayeredPane itself, and then iterate through its components to see which one is located at the Point of mouse click. Also, no one will ask you for your entire program, but your case is certainly not too complicated, not if you boil it down to a [minimal compilable and runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something that yes, will take effort to produce, but often is worth the effort.

Comment: Ok. I didn't mention that there are other components apart from those that may overlap that are on other layers. The objects that may overlap are different instances of the same class and there may be a few hundreds of them. Having 100s of layers is not needed and not that good design I think. And anyway that wouldn't solve my problem to get to know what exactly lays behind the component I click.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted the question. No matter if my approach to software design is the best, the question is simple and straight-foreword. Many components in a JLayeredPane, how to access with mouse those that are below.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter nor your upvoter, but will hold off on trying to answer this pending your posting an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is not a requirement of course, but it would help those who are trying to help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would like to give a mcve but it's difficult. But my question is rather simple. In the 1st picture in [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) there are 5 colored panes. Suppose they are on the same layer and you click on the topleft corner of the green one. My question is how know if other panes are under to the point I clicked. In the pic red, cyan and magenta should be acceded and yellow (probably) not. But suppose the red was smaller and totally hidden under green. How do we know what lies under the green one?

Comment: Your question in its essence is simple, but for me to construct an answer and test it, I would have to create my own [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which as you state "is difficult". Since this is your question, my preference is that the brunt of effort to create this tool should be yours, not mine, but perhaps if you wait longer, someone else will come by, create their own, and solve it for you. If this doesn't happen soon though, consider re-considering your decision not to create one. If you do change your mind, please do notify me to look at it. For now, I'm signing out. Luck!

Comment: Just added working example of what I am trying to do

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically two tasks:

- visit the components in the same layer that are *below* the one that receives the mouseEvent and find the first that contains the mouse location
- if found, manually dispatch the event (and let it handle further dispatches, if necessary)

JLayeredPane api helps with the first, and Component has a method to do the second - the only thingy that needs attention is coordinate transformation where SwingUtilities' helper methods come into play

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) return;
    Component[] siblings = layeredPane.getComponentsInLayer(JLayeredPane.getLayer(this));
    int pos = layeredPane.getPosition(this);
    for (Component sibling : siblings) {
        // interested in siblings below
        if (layeredPane.getPosition(sibling) > pos) {
            // convert coordinates
            Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, evt.getX(), evt.getY(), sibling);
            if (sibling.contains(p)) {
                // convert event
                MouseEvent dispatch = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(
                        this, evt, sibling);
                // manually dispatch the event
                sibling.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    // do my own work
    System.out.println(getName() + evt);
}
```